# How can i control invite links? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

We have got a gaming group. So we have minecraft,fivem,assettocorsa servers. We create a special invitation link to these servers. How can we check which invitation link the person is using?

Event : guildMemberAdd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution online, sorta might be slow but as far as i can tell its the only solution

https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/tracking-used-invites.md

it has a part where it gets the inviter by `client.users.get(invite.inviter.id)` but you can just use built in `invite.inviter` incase you wanted